# MySQL: Grabbing only the users that has only one row?

Tags: mysql, sql

Is what i have:

```
SELECT users.*
            FROM users INNER JOIN roles_users ON users.id = roles_users.user_id 
            WHERE roles_users.role_id IN (1)
            GROUP BY users.id
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

I would like to grab all the users that ONLY has one row, with role_id 1.

The above query grabs all the users that have a row with role_id 1, so it shows also those who have more rows with role_id 2, role_id 3 for example.

So how can i do WHERE roles_users.role_id IN (1) AND NOT in 2,3,4.. something?

Comment: @Lukas Eder that worked like a charm! Why did you remove your answer? Do you also know if I would like to only include the users that has the specified two roles? Example IN(1, 4)? Then a user shouldnt show if it has 2,4 (because 4 matched the query thinks its legit)

Comment: I wasn't very happy with this SQL as it doesn't feel like the best performing solution and is very MySQL-specific (grouping by 1 column, but selecting all columns). But let's undelete, then... I've added a suggestion how to handle `IN (1, 4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an anti-join to exclude those users that also have other roles

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users
INNER JOIN roles_users ON users.id = roles_users.user_id 
-- replace by IN (1, 4) if needed
WHERE roles_users.role_id IN (1)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM roles_users
                 WHERE roles_users.user_id = users.id
                    -- replace by NOT IN (1, 4) if needed
                   AND roles_users.role_id NOT IN (1))
GROUP BY users.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

The above is quite MySQL-specific as normally, you shouldn't select columns that are not part of the `GROUP BY` clause. Besides, maybe it is not best performing, as `roles_users` is joined two times to `users`. I don't know if MySQL can optimise this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested):

```
SELECT users.*, COUNT(*) AS roleX_count
FROM users
INNER JOIN roles_users ON users.id = roles_users.user_id 
GROUP BY users.id, roles_users.role_id
HAVING roleX_count = 1 AND roles_users.role_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users
INNER JOIN roles_users ON users.id = roles_users.user_id 
WHERE roles_users.role_id = 1
and 1 = (select count(*)
         from roles_users
         where users.id = roles_users.user_id)
GROUP BY users.id;
```

Comment: This works nice. Do you also know if I would like to only include the users that has the specified two roles? Example IN(1, 4)? Then a user shouldnt show if it has 2,4 (because 4 matched the query thinks its legit)

Comment: That isn't right because IN means "either or". To have specifically only roles 1 and 4, you need to do: WHERE roles_users.role_id = 1 AND roles_users.role_id = 4, while changing the expected result of the count(*) from 1 to 2.